# How to mirror vertices on uv sheet

Tags: normals, uv-image-editor, mirror

Sorry a newbie question... I have a UV sheet from a mirrored character using normals and displace.
however at some stage some vertices have been moved resulting in a gap on the textures on one side

I have tried to copy half of the verts to the other side I hoped this would reposition the others to the correct places...but it hasn't seemed to work? infact im not sure if I am supposed to copy and paste to the other side and what settings to use in any case...

Any tips to help fix the uvs.

[image: Correct alignment]
[image: Gap in seams]

[image: Texture sheet is split so normal maps can display correctly]

Answer (score 0):

You can select one of the vertices in the UV editor and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to select that patch of your mesh. Then you can move it slightly to correct the position.

To mirror simply scale by -1 on one axis.

Comment: Although that would work moving verts by hand... I would like to be able to take the correct data from one side and apply it to the vertices on the other - this would become more important if changes were made to the sheet down the line since id like to avoid moving vertices by hand. So although you are right, its not quite the answer i'm hoping for.

You also notice the mirrored side is not mirrored on the sheet but a copy moved one sheet space to the left. mirroring would affect the normals and probably invert them. Bumps would become dips.